# Swapping html table elements (the complete object) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: I just noticed that I'm trying to swap integers because I'm getting the rowIndex. That's not what I want to do. I want to swap objects. However, I don't really know how.

I want to move table elements up and down in a queue by swapping with the element above and the element below respectively. However, my code doesn't work. The following is the JS function for the downButton.

```
var downButton = document.getElementsByClassName('downButton')[0];
downButton.onclick = function moveDown(currentRow) {
  var index = currentRow.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var nextRow = currentRow.nextElementSibling.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var temp = index;
  index = nextRow;
  nextRow = temp;
}
```

This is the html for the down button:

```
<button class = "downButton">down</button>
```

Here's a JSFiddle link for the table: https://jsfiddle.net/Led4b3nw/

Comment: Add the HTML for table also. And it would be better if you could add a working snippet or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862006/swapping-rows-using-a-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Swap innerHTML instead of indexes:

```
  var index = currentRow.parentNode.parentNode;
  var nextRow = currentRow.nextElementSibling.parentNode.parentNode;
  var temp = index.innerHTML;
  index.innerHTML = nextRow.innerHTML;
  nextRow.innerHTML = temp;
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: read property 'parentNode' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.moveDown, I'm assuming because of removing rowIndex property.

Comment: This cannot be debugged without your full code then. It seems your currentRow is undefined. Did you forget to pass the value to the function?