# how to moving table rows use javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move the 2nd row to be 1st but I don't know how to proceed. Can someone show me how to proceed ?

Here is my Table example :
[image]

```
<table>
                <caption><h1>Daftar Hasil Campur Warna</h1></caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>kode Primer</td>
                            <td>warna</td>
                            <td>Campur</td>
                            <td>kode Sekunder</td>
                            <td>warna</td>
                            <td>kode Tersier</td>
                            <td>Hasil Warna</td>
                            <td>Aksi</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <?php
                    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="kdPrimer"><?php echo $value['kdPrimer']; ?></td>
                        <td id="warnap"><?php echo $value['warnap']; ?></td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td id="kdSekunder"><?php echo $value['kdSekunder']; ?></td>
                        <td id="warnas"><?php echo $value['warnas']; ?></td>
                        <td id="kdTersier"><?php echo $value['kdTersier']; ?></td>
                        <td id="warnat"><?php echo $value['warnat']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="ubahdata.php?kdPrimer=<?php echo $value['kdPrimer']?>&kdSekunder=<?php echo $value['kdSekunder']?>">Ubah</a>
                            <a href="hapusdata.php?kdPrimer=<?php echo $value['kdPrimer']?>&kdSekunder=<?php echo $value['kdSekunder']?>">Hapus</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>    
                <?php
                    }       
                ?>
```

So I need to make a drag function to move the 2nd row to be 1st row. So what must I do?

Comment: Hi, Image is not shown

Comment: @keff how to show image in here?

Comment: @5180411347-EsaJuniarto You need to remove the code marks (backticks) from around your link

Comment: Just a question: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: we can't re-program a picture. It's useful, but to do anything practical we also need to see some HTML and Javascript

Comment: Done. Here you have: https://u.teknik.io/Mze1v.png ;-)

Comment: "I need to make drag function" ... for this you will need some JavaScript. you can probably find tutorials about dragging and dropping if you google it. What have you researched? What have you tried? You appear to have made very little effort to work on this yourself, before asking for the free time of others. Did you do some googling, even?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862006/swapping-rows-using-a-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a little bit (an extra point to note: I replaced your `id` attributes with `class` as Ids must always be unique on each page!) and made it work without the need of any framework. You *can* of course still do it with jQuery. In that case you should have a closer look at `.before()` (or `.insertBefore()`).

In "Vanilla JavaScript" you can do the following (swapping columns):

```js
function moveColBefore(from,before){
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr')).forEach(r=>{
  // remove superfluous #text nodes ..
  var cn=r.childNodes; 
  for (var i=cn.length;i--;) if (cn[i].nodeName=='#text') r.removeChild(cn[i]);
  // do the actual re-arranging of columns (for each row!)
  r.insertBefore(r.childNodes[from],r.childNodes[before])
 })
}
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',ev=>{
  if(ev.target.nodeName=='BUTTON') 
    moveColBefore(ev.target.dataset.from,ev.target.dataset.before)
})
```

```css
td {background-color:#eee}
```

```html
<table>
<caption><h1>Daftar Hasil Campur Warna</h1></caption>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>kode Primer</td>
    <td>warna</td>
    <td>Campur</td>
    <td>kode Sekunder</td>
    <td>warna</td>
    <td>kode Tersier</td>
    <td>Hasil Warna</td>
    <td>Aksi</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="kdPrimer">kdPrimer</td>
    <td class="warnap">warnap</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td class="kdSekunder">kdSekunder</td>
    <td class="warnas">warnas</td>
    <td class="kdTersier">kdTersier</td>
    <td class="warnat">warnat</td>
    <td> <a href="linktarget1">Ubah</a> <a href="linktarget2">Hapus</a> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button data-from="1" data-before="0" >move 1 before 0</button>
<button data-from="7" data-before="0" >move 7 before 0</button>
```

**Edit: swapping rows**

As I now read from your latest comment (maybe I misread your original post?) you actually want to *swap rows* and *not columns*. This is even easier to achieve, see below:

```js
function moveRowBefore(from,before){
  var tb=document.querySelector('tbody');

  // remove superfluous #text nodes ..
  var cn=tb.childNodes; 
  for (var i=cn.length;i--;) if (cn[i].nodeName=='#text') tb.removeChild(cn[i]);
  // do the actual re-arranging of rows:
  tb.insertBefore(tb.childNodes[from],tb.childNodes[before])
}
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',ev=>{
  if(ev.target.nodeName=='BUTTON') 
    moveRowBefore(ev.target.dataset.from,ev.target.dataset.before)
})
```

```css
td {background-color:#eee}
```

```html
<table>
<caption><h1>Daftar Hasil Campur Warna</h1></caption>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>kode Primer</td>
    <td>warna</td>
    <td>Campur</td>
    <td>kode Sekunder</td>
    <td>warna</td>
    <td>kode Tersier</td>
    <td>Hasil Warna</td>
    <td>Aksi</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="kdPrimer">0000FF</td>
    <td class="warnap">Biru</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td class="kdSekunder">kdSekunder</td>
    <td class="warnas">warnas</td>
    <td class="kdTersier">kdTersier</td>
    <td class="warnat">warnat</td>
    <td> <a href="linktarget1">first</a> <a href="linktarget2">Hapus</a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="kdPrimer">FFFF00</td>
    <td class="warnap">Kuning</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td class="kdSekunder">kdSekunder</td>
    <td class="warnas">warnas</td>
    <td class="kdTersier">kdTersier</td>
    <td class="warnat">warnat</td>
    <td> <a href="linktarget1">second</a> <a href="linktarget2">Hapus</a> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button data-from="1" data-before="0" >move row 1 before row 0</button>
```

Comment: I want to move the 0000FF line to the last line that switches with the FFFF00 line. can u help me? thanks

Comment: That is even simpler, check my edited answer above.